# Big graph can't show in FireFox by Flot

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, internet-explorer-9, flot

I have come across a problem that big graph cannot show in Firefox by Flot library.

Here is my sample.

http://jsfiddle.net/SunMoonStar/9x7aJ/1334/

When I set height to 50000 , I will get such error

```
NS_ERROR_FAILURE: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIDOMCanvasRenderingContext2D.save]
```

I hope anyone can help me with that.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

IE9 tag is because when I set height to 50000 , it can only show half of graph in IE9 .

I think it may the same reason as FireFox .

Comment: Not sure why this is tagged with IE9

Answer (score 1):

Yes; this is a common problem on most/all browsers, not just Firefox.  It's not an issue with Flot, but a limitation of the browser's canvas implementation.

Canvas is designed to work within a single screen, i.e. maximum a few thousand by a few thousand pixels.  This is for a variety of reasons; performance, for example, of pushing 2.5 billion pixels (50k by 50k) would be so terrible as to be practically useless.  So I seriously doubt that the browser developers design or test for such large canvas sizes.

You need to rethink your page's architecture, which probably would not have worked anyway given the performance issues I mentioned above.  I assume, with such an extreme size, that you're doing some kind of scrolling.  Rather than creating a huge canvas and scrolling it within a parent div you should instead use the Flot navigate plugin to scroll the chart data within a much smaller canvas.

Comment: Hello bro, Thank you for you quickly replay. I have tried Highcharts before. And it can show big charts in each kind of browser very well. But unfortunately Highcharts does not free for commercial. I wonder does Flot also provides SVG to draw graph in future? Flot is really good chart tool to fit most of my requirement.

Comment: No, it's very unlikely that Flot will ever use SVG.  Even if it works at larger sizes, you still have to deal with poor performance; charts that large are just not a good approach.